# New virtual network adapters being assigned randomly

Tags: batch-file, system

I have a setup where I clone virtual machines, therefore changing their mac addresses.
When each machine boots up, it gets assigned to a `Local Area Connection x` interface.

I then run a `batch` script that changes the IPs of the interfaces:

```
netsh interface ip set address name="Local Area Connection 1" static 192.168.1.50 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.254
netsh interface ip set address name="Local Area Connection 2" static 172.16.5.50 255.255.255.0 172.16.5.254
```

The problem is that the adapters gets assigned randomly - the first NIC sometimes gets `Local Area Connection 1` and sometimes `Local Area Connection 2`. Therefore I can't assign the IP addresses.

The NICs are ordered correctly by their MAC addresses. I've thought about getting the MAC addresses of the two active interfaces, sort them, and find out the assigned adapter names, and only then run `netsh interface ip set`, however I'm not sure how can I do it.

Any ideas?

Comment: This question is about how change network adapters with scripting. It fits here and nowhere else. If anyone begs to differ, they should migrate it to the proper location, and not close it. This issue is frustrating and may happen to many other people.

Comment: iTayb: perhaps you can repost the question on superuser.com?

Comment: I would migrate it there if i could...

Comment: If I were you, I would register on serverfault.com, create a new question, open the edit of this question and copy paste it to the new question. I know I proposed superuser.com before but sometimes it is not so easy to select the right site to ask a question. Good luck!

Comment: But why should it be a duplicate? Then google will list these two questions, when one is closed. Stack exchanges allows questions to be migrated to different QA sites in the network, in case they fit better somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the `getmac` util to get the MAC addresses along with their assigned connection names:

```
getmac /V /FO LIST
```

There is also a solution with Powershell:
http://www.ddls.net.au/blog/2012/08/renaming-network-connections-using-powershell-and-wmi/